# Como contar PlanilhaGoogle

Tags: google-drive-api

Estou tentando contar alguns dados na planilha para fazer uma estatística, porém, não está dando certo:

Dados de entrada, nas células de `B1` a `B6`

> 4.75x
>   5.76x
>   1.66x
>   11.17x
>   20.76x

Resultado que quero obter

> <= 1.99x  =  1
>   Maior de >1.99x e < 2.99x  =  0
>   Maior de >2.99x e <> 3.99x  =  0
>   Maior de > 4  =  4

**Obs:** Estou usando as formulas em `A8, A9, A10 e A11`

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5;"<1.99x") 
=COUNTIF(A1:A5;"<2.99x")-A8
=COUNTIF(S1:A1:A5;">2.99x")-A11
=COUNTIF(A1:A5;">4.99x")
```

Quem puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Explica melhor os dados de entrada, e o que quer que retorne após a formula. Pelo que está escrito, você ta contando e não somando para verificar se está dentro da condição, ou seria, atribuir uma valor a cada resultado da estatistica conforme regra?

Comment: Quero contar quantos resultados  é menor que 1.99x, está entre 2,00x e 2.99x, está entre 3.00x e 3.99x e mair que 4.00x

Comment: Quero contar quantos resultados  é menor que 1.99x, está entre 2,00x e 2.99x, está entre 3.00x e 3.99x e mair que 4.00x. No exemplo acima os resultados acima de 9.99 cai entre as estatísticas menor que 4....=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ficar mais simples, primeiro vamos tirar o "x" do número, para isso fiz a conversão dos valores para a **coluna B**, de casa linha, de `B1` a `B5`, utilizando a formula:

```
=LEFT($A1;LEN($A1)-1)*1
```

Então temos que `4.75x` tem `5` caracteres, menos `1`, fica `4.75`. Assim removendo o **X**, e o `*1` para converter para Número. E também temos que converter de números com `.` para números com `,`. Sugiro utilizar o Localizar e Substituir <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> do próprio Google.

Ao invés de utilizar o `COUNTIF` vamos utilizar o `COUNTIFS`, que retorna a contagem de um intervalo, dependendo de vários critérios.

Assim, conforme seu dados as linhas de B8 a B11, ficam com as formulas:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B5;"<=1,99")
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5;">1,99";B1:B5;"<2,99")
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5;">2,99";B1:B5;"<3,99")
=COUNTIF(B1:B5;">4")
```

> **Funções utilizadas:**
>   [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=pt-BR) = Retorna o tamanho de uma string.
>   [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=pt-BR) = Retorna uma substring do início de uma string especificada.
>   [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=pt-BR) = Retorna a contagem de um intervalo, dependendo de vários critérios.

Segue exemplo:
[Como contar Planilha Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GualjUQlnDQZ5f4V3IUDLaGNlpBQo1u-KVRaFBJk3_s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Obrigado David, muito bem explicado. Eu apenas mudei o LEN para -4 porque o resultado para estatística vem com "." ao invés de "," ai estava dando erro, como preciso apenas que faça a contagem eu precisei apenas pegar o decimal antes do ponto. Sucesso e Obrigado!!!

Comment: @RodrigoAraujo, tem como vc marcar a resposta como aceita?

Comment: Eu não sei onde marcar?